# Identifying a function with a return type of void in runtime

Tags: dart

I have a function that accepts another function and its arguments as arguments. The return type of the function and its parameter types are unknown. I need to know in runtime if the argument function returns a value or if it is a void function.

```
functionHandler(Function fn, List<dynamic> args) {
  var result = fn(args[0], args[1]);
  if ( -- fn returns a value --)
    doSomething();
  else if ( -- fn is a void function --)
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

I can't use fn.runtimeType because the the parameter types are unknown.

A void function will return null, but then I can't distinguish between a void function and a function that simply returned a null value.

Is there any way I can check in runtime if fn is a function with return type void?

Comment: Do you actually need to distinguish between `void` and non-`void` functions?  If you intend to return `result`, you could do that regardless of the return type.

Comment: Also, `void` functions can (sadly) return non-`null` values too. They generally shouldn't, but if you write `void foo() => something();` as a shorthand for `void foo() { something(); }`, you actually return the result of `something();`.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way would be to use `fn.runtimeType.toString().endsWith('=> void')`.

Since you seem to know that `fn` takes exactly two positional arguments, a better way would be to make `functionHandler` a generic function, fully qualify your `Function` type with parameterized types, and then check the type parameter for the return type:

```dart
dynamic functionHandler<ReturnType, ArgumentType1, ArgumentType2>(
  ReturnType Function(ArgumentType1, ArgumentType2) fn,
  List<dynamic> args,
) {
  // `ReturnType == void` is a syntax error, so we must do a little
  // dance to get its corresponding `Type` object.
  Type getType<T>() => T;

  if (ReturnType == getType<void>()) {
    print('void');
  } else {
    print('non-void');
  }
}

void main() {
  // Test a `void` function.
  void voidFunction(Object arg1, dynamic arg2) {}
  functionHandler(voidFunction, []); // Prints: void

  // Test a function that returns `null`.
  Null nullFunction(int arg1, String? arg2) => null;
  functionHandler(nullFunction, []); // Prints: non-void

  // Test a function with optional arguments.
  int intFunction(int arg1, [int? arg2, int? arg3]) => 0;
  functionHandler(intFunction, []); // Prints: non-void
}
```

Comment: Using `Type.toString` assumes the syntax used for `toString` of `Type` objects of function types, something which is not specified, and has not historically been consistent across platforms. It also gives a false positive for `void Function() Function(int, int)`.
Depending on the type parameter only works if the type arguments are inferred. If you explicitly call `functionHandler<Object?, Never, Never>(anyFunction);`, you don't get to see the return type of `anyFunction`.
Still, I have no strictly *better* approach :)